# XLST to find ASP.NET roles in web.sitemap

Tags: asp.net, xslt, menu, sitemap

I am using the web.sitemap which is created using VS.net 2010 along with a XSLT to create a clean CSS-able menu.
I have modified the xslt from [Cyotec](http://cyotek.com/blog/using-xslt-to-display-an-asp-net-sitemap-without-using-tables) to strip out the first node however I am so far unable to work out how to search within to display only the links depending on the role of the user.

The XSLT is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:map="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="map">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template name="mapNode" match="/">
    <ul id="main-menu">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="map:siteMapNode">
    <xsl:if test="/siteMap/SiteMapNode[@roles != 'Admin']">
            <li>
          <a href="{substring(@url, 2)}" title="{@description}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
          </a>

          <xsl:if test="map:siteMapNode">
            <xsl:call-template name="mapNode"/>
          </xsl:if>

        </li>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode url="~/" title=""  description="Anon" roles="*">
    <siteMapNode url="~/anon.aspx" title="Anon"  description="Anon" roles="*" />
    <siteMapNode url="~/admin1.aspx" title="Admin1"  description="Admin Only" roles="Admin"/>
    <siteMapNode url="~/admin2.aspx" title="Admin2"  description="Admin Only" roles="Admin">
      <siteMapNode url="~/admin3.aspx" title="Admin3"  description="Admin Only" roles="Admin"/>
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

I am wanting to only output the urls titles and descriptions where roles != Admin
Everything works fine without the search.
Is anyone able to shed some light on the 'if' function, or suggest a better way of achieving this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try `<xsl:if test="not(/siteMap/SiteMapNode/@roles = 'Admin')">` or better `<xsl:temlate match="map:siteMapNode[not(@role = 'Admin')]">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your current **xsl:if** condition....

```
<xsl:if test="/siteMap/SiteMapNode[@roles != 'Admin']">
```

.... is that the first forward slash means it is an absolute path, starting from the root element, so all the **xsl:if** is saying is whether there is any **SiteMapNode**, immediately under the **siteMap** element, that is not an Admin role. This means it will always be true in your case.

You really only want to check the role of the current element

```
<xsl:if test="@roles != 'Admin'">
```

However, there is a tidier way of doing this. Remove the **xsl:if** condition, and just have a separate template to match the admin role elements, and ignore them.

```
<xsl:template match="map:siteMapNode[@roles='Admin']"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:map="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="map">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template name="mapNode" match="/">
      <ul id="main-menu">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
      </ul>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="/*/*">     
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>     
   </xsl:template>     

   <xsl:template match="map:siteMapNode[@roles='Admin']"/>

   <xsl:template match="map:siteMapNode">
      <li>
         <a href="{substring(@url, 2)}" title="{@description}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
         </a>
         <xsl:if test="map:siteMapNode">
            <xsl:call-template name="mapNode"/>
         </xsl:if>
      </li>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<ul id="main-menu">
   <li>
      <a href="/anon.aspx" title="Anon">Anon</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Do note the template that matches the admin role element is more specific that the template that matches any **SiteMapNode** element and so the XSLT processor will give priority to this when matching.

Comment: Thank you both Tim C and svz, both of your solutions were spot on the money. As you can see, I am still getting my head around this but when I haven't been able to work out a solution in a day, it is sometimes easier to ask.